# Comparing time series with different timestamps in R

Tags: r, time-series

The problem I have is as follows:

- Several processes are being observed and changes are recorded
- We only have the time of the change and observation value
- Since neither of the time series will have identical set of timestamps, direct comparison between those is not possible
- But we do know, that unless a change was recorded, the observation value stayed the same

How can we check what values were observed at a certain point of time across all processes?
How can we produce periodical aggregates(e.g. a mean daily value) based on known information?

Here is a mockup of the data:

```
tsVector1 <- c("2020-01-01 16:18", "2020-01-03 12:12", "2020-01-03 14:56", "2020-01-10 09:48", "2020-01-11 23:00")
tsVector2 <- c("2020-01-01 16:18", "2020-01-02 14:10", "2020-01-04 18:36", "2020-01-06 19:23", "2020-01-10 21:10")
tsVector3 <- c("2020-01-01 16:18", "2020-01-05 13:37", "2020-01-08 01:11")
obsVector1 <- c(1, 1.2, 1.6, 3, 3.8)
obsVector2 <- c(1, 1.4, 1.7, 1.8, 2.1)
obsVector3 <- c(1:3)
procVector1 <- rep("proc1", 5)
procVector2 <- rep("proc2", 5)
procVector3 <- rep("proc3", 3)
tsDF <- data.frame(ts = as.POSIXct(c(tsVector1, tsVector2, tsVector3)),
                   observation = c(obsVector1, obsVector2, obsVector3), 
                   process = c(procVector1, procVector2, procVector3))
```

I am looking for an output like this:

```
SomeHelpfulFunction(tsDF, "2020-01-07 01:00")
>  process  observation
> process1  1.6
> process2  1.8
> process3  2.0
```

Is there a way to get this data without resorting to loops or replication of all unique timestamps across all of the time series being compared?

---

UPDATE:
Having had a look at the replies and testing them out with a bigger dataset, I found that the `data.table` method works best for my use case and also results in faster response times. To give you an idea, the times I have measured were:

- 33.46s - `data.table`
- 49.36s - base R `duplicated()`
- 219.53s - `dplyr` with `top_n()` instead of `slice_tail()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cute solution using a rolling join in `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

SomeHelpfulFunction <- function(tsDF, time) {
  a = data.table(tsDF,
                 key=c("process", "ts"))
  b = data.table(process = unique(tsDF$process),
                 ts = as.POSIXct(time),
                 key = c("process", "ts"))
  a[b, roll=TRUE]
}

SomeHelpfulFunction(tsDF, "2020-01-07 1:00")
#>                     ts observation process
#> 1: 2020-01-07 01:00:00         1.6   proc1
#> 2: 2020-01-07 01:00:00         1.8   proc2
#> 3: 2020-01-07 01:00:00         2.0   proc3
```

I found this blog post useful in explaining rolling joins: https://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2016/06/understanding-datatable-rolling-joins.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the last value before the time you are querying, for every process. With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

tsDF %>% 
  group_by(process) %>% 
  arrange(ts) %>% 
  filter(ts <= "2020-01-07 01:00") %>% 
  slice_tail() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-ts)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  observation process
        <dbl> <fct>  
1         1.6 proc1  
2         1.8 proc2  
3         2   proc3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, unfortunately I cannot install a source version of `dplyr`, and the binary one (0.8.5) does not appear to include `slice_tail()`, so this solution may be problematic for someone in a similar situation

Comment: Hi bmonger, you can replace the `slice_tail` with `top_n(1, ts)` for older versions of dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an additional way of achieving the ruslt with base R alone. But it relies on `duplicated()` and is only good for getting the last reading, so will not really work with applications where with last N readings are required:

```
SomeHelpfulFunction <- function(tsDF, time) {
    functionLocalDF <- tsDF[order(tsDF$process, tsDF$ts), ]
    functionLocalDF <- functionLocalDF[functionLocalDF$ ts <= time, ]
    functionLocalDF[!duplicated(functionLocalDF$process, fromLast = T), ]
}
```